# Calculating ideal weight, given a gender and height. How can we convert int to inches?

Tags: php

The calculation for the "female" option is found by multiplying her height in inches by 3.5 and subtracting 108. The calculation if "male" is selected will be found by multiplying his height in inches by 4 and subtracting 128. I am not sure how to translate this into a php function. This calculation is processed upon pushing a submit button. My goal is to calculate the ideal weight of the given gender and height.

Currently I am unable to display the $result. Does anyone see my error?

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender']: 0;
$height = (int)$_POST['height'];

switch ($gender) {

    case 2:
        $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
        break;

    case 1:
        $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
        break;

    default:
        $result = 0;
}

echo "Ideal Weight:", $result;
}
?> 

<html>
<div align="center">
<body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
        Select Your Gender: <select name="gender">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="0">Female</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Enter Your Height: <input type="number" name="height">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate"/>
    </form>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: at least give it a try, its kind of trivial

Comment: I am confused how to calculate the two different questions for the given selected value. I've tried multiple ways, but can't seem to get it right. @Dagon

Comment: No need to be toxic. I've tried different methods to calculating the ideal weight for the given gender, just having trouble with the execution. My goal here is to discover if there is an easier solution to this problem. @Dagon

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender']: 0;
    $height = (int)$_POST['height'];
    switch ($gender) {
        case 1:
            $multiplier = 3.5;
            $substract = 108;
            break;
        case 0:
        default:
            $multiplier = 4;
            $substract = 128;
            break;
    }

    $result = ($height * $multiplier) - $substract;
    //Do whatever you want to do with $result
}
?>
```

This is just a rough example, conversion to inches is not done, it's only to show a way to calculate the result.

Comment: This helps! I had a solution close to this, now I just have to get the conversion and result display down.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand this correctly, is this the way you want to calculate the height?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender']: 0;
    $height = (int)$_POST['height'];

    switch ($gender) {

        case 2:
            $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
            break;

        case 1:
            $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
            break;

        default:
            $result = 0;
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: We are calculating and displaying the ideal weight in this problem. @Timphs