# Conversion of an int to inches and displaying the result as an echo

Tags: php

Here we are selecting a gender from a dropDownMenu, then inputting a height. This height needs to be converted into inches. For some reason, the final result is not displaying with the current code. I believe the problem may lie in the way I am trying to echo the $result variable.

Context: The ideal weight for a woman is found by multiplying her height in inches by 3.5 and subtracting 108. The ideal weight for a man is found by multiplying his height in inches by 4 and subtracting 128.

I need to find an easy way to display the result, whether that be an echo or it being displayed in a textbox. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender']: 0;
$height = (int)$_POST['height'];

switch ($gender) {
case 0:
    $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
    break;
case 1:
    $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
    break;
default:
    $result = 0; 
} echo "Ideal Weight: ". $result .'Unit';
}
?>
<html>
<div align="center">
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Select Your Gender: <select name="gender">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="0">Female</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Enter Your Height: <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="unit inches">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Your Ideal Weight"/>
</form>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that the result is only echoed in the "default" part of your `switch` statement. So,  it is only displayed if `$gender` is not set to 1 or 2. Try moving the `echo` to after the `switch` statement.

Comment: @showdev Check out the edit, with this, I am getting syntax errors on the echo line after the switch statement, and on the line below that for case.

Comment: I meant to put the `echo` after you close the `switch { ... }`. Sorry for the confusion. See the answer below by Baron.

Comment: Edited: Does that look right? This fix still does not display $result. @showdev

Comment: What is the difference between this post and your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989739/calculating-ideal-weight-given-a-gender-and-height-how-can-we-convert-int-to-i)?

Comment: Different problem. I've got it all set up in a different way than I originally had it, the problem is now getting the proper $result to echo. @showdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case value not same with option value and echo after close switch. Try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender']: 0;
    $height = (int)$_POST['height'];

    switch ($gender) {
        case 0:
            $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
            break;
        case 1:
            $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
            break;
        default:
            $result = 0; 
    }

    echo "Ideal Weight: ". $result .'Unit';

}
?>
<html>
<div align="center">
<body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
        Select Your Gender: <select name="gender">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="0">Female</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Enter Your Height: <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="unit inches">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Your Ideal Weight"/>
    </form>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Result is still failing to display. Could there be an easier way to write this? @showdev